# React: Getting the value of text inside a contentEditable div

Tags: html, reactjs

I am using a `contentEditable` div and want to get the text inside it when a submit is called. I tried `this.refs.textarea.value.trim()` but that doesn't seem to work. My code is as follows in the render return

```
<div><form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="noter-save-form" method="POST">

<div id="noter-text-area" contentEditable="true" ref="textarea">{value}</div>
```

and the `handleSubmit` function.

```
handleSubmit: function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = this.refs.textarea.value.trim();
  alert(text);
  this.saveFile(text);
},
```

Thanks for the help. I am just looking to replace the text variable with what is actually inside the editable div.

Comment: Have you tried `this.refs.textarea.innerHTML.trim();` instead?

Comment: try `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.textarea)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if it's a div it doesn't matter if it's editable and should be `this.refs.textarea.innerHTML` and if you just want text `this.refs.textarea.innerText`

Answer (score 2):

This works for me! hope this help

```
 handleSubmit: function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      let text = e.currentTarget.textContent;
      alert(text);
      this.saveFile(text);
    },
```