# Show editable data with textarea

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to make something editable with the following code

```
class RuleDescriptionViewAdmin extends Component {
render(){

    var rule = this.props.rule.description;
    console.log(rule);
    return(
    <div>
    <Col smOffset={2} mdOffset={1}>
    <PageHeader>
        {this.props.rule.title}
    </PageHeader>
    </Col>
    <textarea>
        {rule.split('\n').map((item, key) => {
          return <span key={key}><Col smOffset={2} mdOffset={1} sm={6}>{item}</Col><br/></span>
          })}
    </textarea>

     </div>
    );

    }
}
```

and I get the following error

> textarea can only have at most one child.

Is there a better way to make this editable?

Edit: I've added the following code

```
<div contentEditable="true" ref={this.divRef}>
        {rule.split('\n').map((item, key) => {
return <span key={key}><Col smOffset={2} mdOffset={1} sm={6}>{item}</Col><br/></span>
    })}
</div>
```

and on `handleOnClick` I'm trying to do this

```
var text = this.divRef.current.innerText;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After troubles with refs and content editable div I did this with draftJS instead of textarea or div

thanks Chayim for the patience and the answers

just in case someone checks this question with the same problem this is the code I used to show editable text with draftJS.

```
class RuleDescriptionViewAdmin extends Component {
constructor(props,context){
    super(props,context);
    this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);

    const processedHTML = DraftPasteProcessor.processHTML(this.props.rule.description.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
    const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(processedHTML); 
    var editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
    var editorState = EditorState.moveFocusToEnd(editorState);
    this.state = {editorState: editorState};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
}



handleOnClick(event) {
  var url = 'http://localhost:8080/rules/' + this.props.rule.id;
  const blocks =  convertToRaw(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()).blocks;
  const value = blocks.map(block => (!block.text.trim() && '\n') ||   block.text).join('\n');
  //do something with value

} 

render(){

    return(
    <div>
    <Col smOffset={2} mdOffset={1}>
    <PageHeader>
        {this.props.rule.title}
    </PageHeader>
    <Editor
      editorState={this.state.editorState}
      onChange={this.onChange}
    />
    </Col>

     <Col smOffset={2} mdOffset={1}>
    <Button onClick = {this.handleOnClick}>Update rule</Button>
    </Col>
    </div>
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `<div contenteditable="true">` instead of `<textarea>`.

Comment: How can I get the value of that div?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767052/react-getting-the-value-of-text-inside-a-contenteditable-div

Comment: I'm getting the following error even on div scope   this.refs.textarea is undefined

Comment: @JoseCarlosPB Did you append `ref="textarea"` to the `<div>` declaration, as shown there?

Comment: Yes, the div is like this   <div contentEditable="true" ref="textarea">

Comment: @JoseCarlosPB I googled it' and now string refs aren't supported because some issues. Instead, use `React.createRef()`. For more information, see https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html.

Comment: I'm trying to get the text with  this.myRef.current.innerText but I'm getting most times that this.myRef.current is null

Comment: Why `current`? Simply `this.myRef.innerText`! No?

Comment: When I print with console.log     this.myRef I get that is something like this  Object {current: div}   inside current there are a lot of elements, one of them is innerText, if I try this.myRef.innerCurrent it return nulls, and this.myRef.current.innerText returns an error because current is null. also I know that InnerText is not null because I've checked the value with console.log(this.myRef)  edit:  sometimes this.myRef.current works and gives me the div without the Object{} but if I use this.myRef.current.innerText it says  current is null... why

Comment: @JoseCarlosPB Please attach your code (maybe the context will help we to understand the problem).